# Heroku deployment - dead pages "We're sorry, but something went wrong."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Pretty new to rails/heroku.  I created a clean project to help figure out what in the world is happening with heroku.  Then I add to it with a:

```
rails generate controller Pages home contact
```

http://localhost:3000/pages/home shows exactly what we expect.  Commit, push to git, push to heroku.  Open the page on heroku and it returns the error page: "We're sorry, but something went wrong."

heroku logs don't seem to have anything interesting, and exceptional isn't registering that anything bad is happenin at all.

UPDATE: I've reduced the logs to an example of the offending bits.

```
2011-10-06T01:06:05+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/pages/home" for 97.87.14.192 at 2011-10-05 18:06
:05 -0700
2011-10-06T01:06:05+00:00 app[web.1]:
2011-10-06T01:06:05+00:00 app[web.1]: ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished (ActiveRecord::Connecti
onNotEstablished):
2011-10-06T01:06:05+00:00 app[web.1]:
2011-10-06T01:06:05+00:00 app[web.1]:
2011-10-06T01:06:05+00:00 app[web.1]:
2011-10-06T01:06:05+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /pages/home] miss
```

Here's the gemfile I'm running

```
# gemfile
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.1.0'

group :test do
  gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.6.1'
  gem 'webrat', '0.7.1'
end

group :development, do
  gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.6.1'
end
```

Comment: Thanks for taking a look, guys.  I added the Heroku logs.  If there's something there I don't know what it is.

Comment: janders is right, its probably a database.yml error thats stopping it. make sure that you have the right gems in your gemfile and do a bundle just in case. p.s. you might want to take your email out of those logs just in case. :)

Comment: Ok, my gemfile seems most suspect because that is literally all I've changed before the `generate controller`.  I'm putting up a copy of that for examination.

Comment: Did you do a `heroku rake db:migrate` ? This might help you out: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/quickstart#prerequisites

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This is just a generic heroku error so you don't display sensitive info to end users. Just type `heroku logs` in rails root and you should see the latest server details including your error.

If you have to run migrations the command is:

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

(Thanks to lampshady)

Comment: This is the answer, sort of!  I got errors when I tried to rake, and that led me to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747002/heroku-rails-3-and-sqlite3) - I updated my gemfile, pushed and raked again.  Bam!

Comment: Yes, and more importantly I have some resources bookmarked to prevent future me some pain.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Migrate your database on heroku then redeploy the app and restart the heroku server. Thats all you need to do.

```
  heroku rake db:migrate

  git push heroku master

  heroku restart
```

Answer (score 1):

Running the logs '`heroku logs`', has a key giveaway: `PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "<Rails Model>" does not exist`. This entry states your model could not be loaded.

To provide an update to previous answers, `heroku rake` has been deprecated. Heroku requires:

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

From your heroku log `ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished (ActiveRecord::Connecti
onNotEstablished):`. From the [Rails API Doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionNotEstablished.html), this error is raised when a connection to the database could not be established. I am guessing that your error may be in your `database.yml` file, most likely parameters not set for your production database.