# Unable to deploy Git repo project into Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sqlite

I have followed below steps:

```
git clone git://github.com/heroku/ruby-sample.git
cd ruby-sample
heroku create
git push heroku master
heroku open
```

When I'm trying to run the 4th step I'm getting below error:

```
$ git push heroku master
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '50.19.85.156' to the list of known hosts.
Counting objects: 63, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (49/49), done.
Writing objects: 100% (63/63), 25.99 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 63 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Ruby/Rails app detected
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.3.2
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin --deployment
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Installing rake (10.1.0)
       Installing i18n (0.6.5)
       Installing multi_json (1.7.9)
       Installing activesupport (3.2.14)
       Installing builder (3.0.4)
       Installing activemodel (3.2.14)
       Installing erubis (2.7.0)
       Installing journey (1.0.4)
       Installing rack (1.4.5)
       Installing rack-cache (1.2)
       Installing rack-test (0.6.2)
       Installing hike (1.2.3)
       Installing tilt (1.4.1)
       Installing sprockets (2.2.2)
       Installing actionpack (3.2.14)
       Installing mime-types (1.24)
       Installing polyglot (0.3.3)
       Installing treetop (1.4.15)
       Installing mail (2.5.4)
       Installing actionmailer (3.2.14)
       Installing arel (3.0.2)
       Installing tzinfo (0.3.37)
       Installing activerecord (3.2.14)
       Installing activeresource (3.2.14)
       Installing coffee-script-source (1.6.3)
       Installing execjs (2.0.1)
       Installing coffee-script (2.2.0)
       Installing rack-ssl (1.3.3)
       Installing json (1.8.0)
       Installing rdoc (3.12.2)
       Installing thor (0.18.1)
       Installing railties (3.2.14)
       Installing coffee-rails (3.2.2)
       Installing jquery-rails (3.0.4)
       Using bundler (1.3.2)
       Installing rails (3.2.14)
       Installing sass (3.2.10)
       Installing sass-rails (3.2.6)
       Installing sqlite3 (1.3.8)
       Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
       /tmp/build_2wj8rtu1t0j1d/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/bin/ruby extconf.rb
       checking for sqlite3.h... no
       sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal'
       or 'yum install sqlite-devel' and check your shared library search path (the
       location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
       *** extconf.rb failed ***
       Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
       libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
       need configuration options.
       Provided configuration options:
       --with-opt-dir
       --without-opt-dir
       --with-opt-include
       --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
       --with-opt-lib
       --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
       --with-make-prog
       --without-make-prog
       --srcdir=.
       --curdir
       --ruby=/tmp/build_2wj8rtu1t0j1d/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/bin/ruby
       --with-sqlite3-dir
       --without-sqlite3-dir
       --with-sqlite3-include
       --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
       --with-sqlite3-lib
       --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/
       --enable-local
       --disable-local
       Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_2wj8rtu1t0j1d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8 for inspection.
       Results logged to /tmp/build_2wj8rtu1t0j1d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
       An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.8), and Bundler cannot continue.
       Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.8'` succeeds before bundling.
       Bundler Output: Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Installing rake (10.1.0)
       Installing i18n (0.6.5)
       Installing multi_json (1.7.9)
       Installing activesupport (3.2.14)
       Installing builder (3.0.4)
       Installing activemodel (3.2.14)
       Installing erubis (2.7.0)
       Installing journey (1.0.4)
       Installing rack (1.4.5)
       Installing rack-cache (1.2)
       Installing rack-test (0.6.2)
       Installing hike (1.2.3)
       Installing tilt (1.4.1)
       Installing sprockets (2.2.2)
       Installing actionpack (3.2.14)
       Installing mime-types (1.24)
       Installing polyglot (0.3.3)
       Installing treetop (1.4.15)
       Installing mail (2.5.4)
       Installing actionmailer (3.2.14)
       Installing arel (3.0.2)
       Installing tzinfo (0.3.37)
       Installing activerecord (3.2.14)
       Installing activeresource (3.2.14)
       Installing coffee-script-source (1.6.3)
       Installing execjs (2.0.1)
       Installing coffee-script (2.2.0)
       Installing rack-ssl (1.3.3)
       Installing json (1.8.0)
       Installing rdoc (3.12.2)
       Installing thor (0.18.1)
       Installing railties (3.2.14)
       Installing coffee-rails (3.2.2)
       Installing jquery-rails (3.0.4)
       Using bundler (1.3.2)
       Installing rails (3.2.14)
       Installing sass (3.2.10)
       Installing sass-rails (3.2.6)
       Installing sqlite3 (1.3.8)
       Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

       /tmp/build_2wj8rtu1t0j1d/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/bin/ruby extconf.rb
       checking for sqlite3.h... no
       sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal'
       or 'yum install sqlite-devel' and check your shared library search path (the
       location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
       *** extconf.rb failed ***
       Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
       libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
       need configuration options.

       Provided configuration options:
       --with-opt-dir
       --without-opt-dir
       --with-opt-include
       --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
       --with-opt-lib
       --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
       --with-make-prog
       --without-make-prog
       --srcdir=.
       --curdir
       --ruby=/tmp/build_2wj8rtu1t0j1d/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/bin/ruby
       --with-sqlite3-dir
       --without-sqlite3-dir
       --with-sqlite3-include
       --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
       --with-sqlite3-lib
       --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/
       --enable-local
       --disable-local


       Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_2wj8rtu1t0j1d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8 for inspection.
       Results logged to /tmp/build_2wj8rtu1t0j1d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
       An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.8), and Bundler cannot continue.
       Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.8'` succeeds before bundling.
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !     
 !     Detected sqlite3 gem which is not supported on Heroku.
 !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/Rails app

To git@heroku.com:shrouded-brushlands-7248.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:shrouded-brushlands-7248.git'
```

Can any one help me deploy?

Comment: Duplicate of [Pushing Rails with SQLite3 to Heroku fails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747002/pushing-rails-with-sqlite3-to-heroku-fails)

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is with `sqlite3` gem:

```
An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.8), and Bundler cannot continue.
```

You have to add the `pg` gem to your `Gemfile` in `production` group, since Heroku uses PostgreSQL.

You can continue using `sqlite3` in your `development` and `test` groups.

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end        

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
```

More info here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#connecting-in-ruby

Answer (score 1):

1)First of all you have to install `sqlite3` on your os and all library  `sqlite-devel`

2) Then in Gemfile

```
group :production do
 gem 'pg'
end        

group :development, :test do
 gem 'sqlite3'
end
```

3) `bundle install`

4)`git add ..`

5) `git commit -m "..."`

6) `git push heroku master`