# Heroku Precompiling asset with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I found this error while running "git push heroku master". I have tried all the available solutions on stackoverflow but doesn't work for me.

```
gems/sprockets-rails-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:60:in `block       (2 levels) i
n define'
       Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
       (See full trace by running task with --trace)
 !
 !     Precompiling assets failed.
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app

To git@heroku.com:aqueous-eyrie-6143.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:aqueous-eyrie-  6143.git'
```

here is my production log

Comment: Are you using the gem 'rails_12factor'? https://github.com/heroku/rails_12factor

Comment: I think you should get answer from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24342178/heroku-push-failed-when-i-run-git-push-heroku-master-command/24342240#24342240) link.

Comment: @steel yes i am using rails_12factor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should run the `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production` on your local machine and look at the `production.log` for possible errors before pushing to heroku

Comment: i am new to heroku, git and ruby on rails so it will be very thankful if u can provide details.

Comment: On running RAILS_ENV=production it gives error "RAILS_ENV is not recognized as an internal or external command"

Comment: and on running rake assets:precompile it is showing rake aborted! message